# Toast is placed out of position in Native Base

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

### Environments

```
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-location": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~13.1.0",
    "native-base": "^3.3.11",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-maps": "0.29.4",
```

### Details

Hello.
I am facing an error which is Toast is placed out of position.
Let's say I use Toast multiple times while I use an app.
A toast is placed on the right position at the first time. However, if I call that again, this is placed under the position where the previous Toast is set and this behavior is repeated every time I call Toast.

- 1st time
  [image: IMG_4576 Medium]
- 2nd times
  [image: IMG_4577 Medium]
- 3rd times
  [image: IMG_4578 Medium]

After a toast disappears, it still leaves on the screen according to React Native Debugger like that image.

I couldn't find solutions anywhere. I would like you to tell me some solution.
Thank you.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Have you found a solution yet?